# How to change Console Application's name in Task Manager?

Tags: c++, winapi, console-application, title, taskmanager

I'm making a console application, and if I use `SetConsoleTitle()` it changes the console's window name, but in Task Manager the process name is basically just the file description. I'm using Dev-C++. Does someone know how to fix this?

Comment: This is working as designed. Task Manager's "Applications" tab displays the window title, and the "Processes" tab displays the Description from the `.exe` file's version info. There is nothing to fix.